# Additional Drivers tool in Ubuntu 12.10?

Tags: drivers, 12.10

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I install extra drivers?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/47506/how-do-i-install-extra-drivers)

So I just upgraded to Ubuntu 12.10 and noticed that the Additional Drivers tool is gone. So how do I install the Proprietary drivers for my PC?

Comment: Go to software sources.