# From where can I install my nVidia drivers?

Tags: installation, drivers, nvidia, 12.10

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I install extra drivers?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/47506/how-do-i-install-extra-drivers)
>   [Additional Drivers tool in Ubuntu 12.10?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/204322/additional-drivers-tool-in-ubuntu-12-10)

I have read [here](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/BinaryDriverHowto/Nvidia) and [here](http://www.ehow.com/how_5976269_update-drivers-ubuntu.html) that I should be able to install drivers. So I'm finding the **Additional Drivers** menu. To install nVidia driver. I started looking for `System -> Administration` and not finding it. I have an icon that says `System Settings` and it has any option related to drivers.

NOTE: I am using Ubuntu 12.10.

Answer (score 1):

Since Quantal Quetzal the **Additional Drivers** application is not installed by default in Ubuntu. But you can search for `Software Sources` in the dash and look at the `Additional drivers` tab.

You can also go to `System configurations` and you will see **Software Sources** right there.